# Symfony version 3 gives 500 server error

Tags: php, symfony

When I use symfony 2.8 and lower on a php server the project works fine but when I use symfony 3 I get 500 server error (That error does not come from symfony error handler, it's from Chrome. There is no log file neither cache).

Why I cannot use Symfony 3.
There is the php configuration from the server.
See the full at https://jsfiddle.net/guervyl/o66hsyu4/

```css
<style type="text/css"> body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

body,
td,
th,
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

pre {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

a:link {
  color: #000099;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.center th {
  text-align: center !important;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  font-size: 75%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 125%;
}

.p {
  text-align: left;
}

.e {
  background-color: #ccccff;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}

.h {
  background-color: #9999cc;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}

.v {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #000000;
}

.vr {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  text-align: right;
  color: #000000;
}

img {
  float: right;
  border: 0px;
}

hr {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  color: #000000;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
      <tr class="h">
        <td>
          <h1 class="p">PHP Version 5.4.41</h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
        <tr class="v">
          <td>
            This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
            <br />Zend&nbsp;Engine&nbsp;v2.4.0,&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;(c)&nbsp;1998-2014&nbsp;Zend&nbsp;Technologies
            <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;with&nbsp;the&nbsp;ionCube&nbsp;PHP&nbsp;Loader&nbsp;+&nbsp;Intrusion&nbsp;Protection&nbsp;from&nbsp;ioncube24.com&nbsp;(disabled)&nbsp;v5.0.7,&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;(c)&nbsp;2002-2015,&nbsp;by&nbsp;ionCube&nbsp;Ltd.
            <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;with&nbsp;Zend&nbsp;Guard&nbsp;Loader&nbsp;v3.3,&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;(c)&nbsp;1998-2013,&nbsp;by&nbsp;Zend&nbsp;Technologies
            <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div></body>
```

My server log:

```
Mon, 04 Jan 2016 19:46:51 -0500 AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol12_3/byethost16.com/b16_17125264/mine.byethost16.com/htdocs/src/
Mon, 04 Jan 2016 19:46:51 -0500 AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol12_3/byethost16.com/b16_17125264/mine.byethost16.com/htdocs/app/
Mon, 04 Jan 2016 19:46:51 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol12_3/byethost16.com/b16_17125264/mine.byethost16.com/htdocs/favicon.ico
Mon, 04 Jan 2016 19:47:35 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol12_3/byethost16.com/b16_17125264/mine.byethost16.com/htdocs/icons/text.gif
Mon, 04 Jan 2016 19:47:46 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol12_3/byethost16.com/b16_17125264/mine.byethost16.com/htdocs/favicon.ico
Mon, 04 Jan 2016 20:45:53 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol12_3/byethost16.com/b16_17125264/mine.byethost16.com/htdocs/web/app_dev.php
Mon, 04 Jan 2016 20:47:51 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol12_3/byethost16.com/b16_17125264/mine.byethost16.com/htdocs/web/
```

Comment: Show us your server's error log.

Comment: Your web server does not allow to access the source files of your application and it cannot find a lot of other files. Check your web server configuration and the file permissions about that. Do you also really try to access the dev front controller on a publicly available server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your HTML code, you are on PHP 5.4

Actually, Symfony3 require a minimum version of PHP 5.5.9, while Symfony2 require a minimum version of PHP 5.3.9.

I think that is your issue.

Also, if you will upgrade your PHP version, I'll advice you to consider PHP 7.0.

Comment: There are two CVE security issues already with 7.0 (fixed in 7.0.1). It is never good advice to jump on the latest version of PHP. Best advice at the moment is to use 5.6.

Comment: Thank you. Where do find the requirements. I check the Sysmfony requirements page, I have all and your answer is correct. But is there another website page I can visit for better requirements? I know this is another answer but, Symfony2.8 needs a minimum version of PHP 5.3.9 but, when I run my 2.8 project I get T_Class error from Doctrine so, Object::class is from PHP 5.5. Why is that.

Comment: Hello. Symfony requirements can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html). About your error, it would be better to open a new question, and provide as many details as you can

Comment: I have synfony3 working on php 5.4 - without issues. I think I could also get it to work on 5.3 (doctrine orm 2.5 pulled support for php 5.3 but Doctrine 2.4.8 works fine) - you just have to be a little bit more careful of what php functions you use.  Generally the only problems I had are with full qualified class names - and they are easly fixed